# Getting WhiteSpace in URL while building Django app using Rest-Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

While building Geo App using Django(3.1.2) and DjangoRestFramework(3.12), while running server get Error - 404. It believe it likely to whitespace in url"

Using the URLconf defined in web_analysis.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
api/ directions/(?P<start_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<start_floor>\d+)&(?P<end_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<end_floor>\d+)&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/% [name='directions']
api/ directions/(?P<start_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<start_floor>\d+)&(?P<end_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<end_floor>\d+)&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/%\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='directions']
api/ directions/(?P<start_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<end_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/% [name='route-room-to-room']
api/ directions/(?P<start_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<end_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/%\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='route-room-to-room']
api/ directions/(?P<room_num>\d{5})/% [name='room-center']
api/ directions/(?P<room_num>\d{5})/%\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='room-center']
api/ rooms/% [name='room-list']
api/ rooms/%\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='room-list']
```

The current path, api/, didn't match any of these.

Below are urls.py files from Root & Project Folder:

Root - urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

Project - urls.py

```
   **from django.urls import re_path from rest_framework.urlpatterns
     import format_suffix_patterns from api import views

     urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'directions/(?P<start_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<start_floor>\d+)&(?P<end_coord>[-]?\d+\.?\d+,\d+\.\d+),(?P<end_floor>\d+)&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/%', views.create_route,name='directions'),
    re_path(r'directions/(?P<start_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<end_room_num>\d{5})&(?P<route_type>[0-9])/%', views.route_room_to_room, name='route-room-to-room'),
     re_path(r'directions/(?P<room_num>\d{5})/%', views.get_room_centroid_node, name='room-center'),
     re_path(r'rooms/%', views.room_list, name='room-list'),
    ]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)**
```

Please suggest, what is wrong/incorrect here?

Comment: The whitespace is not part of the real url, this is just *rendering*, to make it clear where the `include` begins.

Comment: What is the `%` doing at the end?

Comment: Had removed % but still the same error.

Comment: so you are visiting `/api/`? But there is no path in the `api.urls` with `path('', ...)`/`re_path('', ...)`.